# What is the correct way of doing JQuery/AJAX and php, file structure?

Tags: php, jquery

what way should I structure my files when doing Jquery AJAX requests in PHP.

i.e.

- showRecords.htm  - contains jQuery/AJAX that gets data (HTML) from the php file below.
- showRecords.php - contains php that does some processing, likely to get data from DB and echo  some HTML.

or

one file:

- showRecords.php - contains the JQuery/AJAX and is the php file and requests data from itself.

> also you clever people out there, please note I am a beginner in JQuery
>   and AJAX so please forgive me if its a silly question or trivial.

Comment: It's not silly or trivial it's the right to start with , from my experience I would use two files for separation because that will help a lot when maintained or scaled or even tracked

Comment: It depends if you have a lot of file with Ajax. Managing only one file will give you smaller count of file. Personally i prefer to make 2 PHP files, one for the main page, and one for the ajax process, in order to be clear and avoid confusing script.

Comment: Thanks guys, I agree with Sedz which most of you agree with. wish me luck in learning quest.

Comment: probably better to have a separate php file that takes the AJAX request, does the db interactions, and sends the data back to your showRecords.htm. By the way, they can both be php files. I mean you could have showRecords.php be the main file, and showRecordsAJAX.php be the ajax handler. I put php into pretty much all my files, so mine are all .php or .phtml.

Comment: thanks Buttle, I like your answer it makes sense.

Comment: You're welcome. I just edited and added a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously not: one file.

I'd do it this way:

- showRecords.php - form processing, db requests
- templates/showSomeHtml.php - displays everything that your users can see
- showRecords.js - jQuery/AJAX that gets data

And if the jQuery/Ajax modifies the HTML, you could also move that (the dynamic HTML) into the templates (read about [javascript templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates))

Comment: Or take that one step further even - MVC+JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's up to you. If you have a quick ajax call you'd like to do and you know it won't be used anywhere but there then I see no issue with having everything in one file. On the other hand, you might need to access that processing script in multiple locations on your site. If that's the case, it's not ideal to place it all in one file. I think two files avoids confusion. Keeps everything separate and neat.

Comment: thanks, I think for a guy like me, less confusion is better, so 2 file approach maybe a good idea. Thank you for your input.

Comment: No problem! I'd go with two files as well.